# Laradock: Laravel queue worker can't connect to RabbitMQ

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq, laradock

I've set up a Laravel (5.6) application with RabbitMQ (3.7.6) using the latest Laradock and composer-installed
https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq . When I start the Laravel message worker with `php artisan queue:work` I'm getting the following error

```
local.ERROR: AMQP error while attempting pop: stream_socket_client(): 
unable to connect to tcp://127.0.0.1:5672 (Connection refused)
```

However, I can connect to Rabbit using `telnet 127.0.0.1 5672` (the connection is closed after 10 seconds of inactivity). The listeners seem to be working correctly:

```
{listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"},{http,15672,"::"}]}
```

I've also checked the RabbitMQ logs, but nothing shows up there. So I assume it's a problem on the client side but I'm not sure where to look.

RabbitMQ settings in Laravel `.env`

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=rabbitmq
RABBITMQ_QUEUE=default
RABBITMQ_DSN=amqp:
```

Laradock `.env`

```
RABBITMQ_NODE_HOST_PORT=5672
RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_HTTP_HOST_PORT=15672
RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_HTTPS_HOST_PORT=15671
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Some progress: There's a separate container for the queue worker (http://laradock.io/documentation/#run-laravel-queue-worker) and you need to put `RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq` in your .env. Still not able to add jobs to the queue, though.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the `implements ShouldQueue` on the line with the class definition of my Notification class. Also, I had to build php-worker with `bcadd` and `mongodb` extensions.

```
RUN pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli mbstring pdo pdo_mysql tokenizer xml pcntl bcmath
```